# Stack Overflow Careers openid.stackauth.com 500 error

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, 500-server-error

When I try to login to Stack Overflow Careers from here: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/login, I get redirected to this URL: https://openid.stackauth.com/Account/LogOn and get a 500 error.

[image: 500 error after logging in]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error should now be fixed.

Thanks a lot for your report!